# Ionic 2 : Run a background service with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2

I use Ionic 2 and I want to my app do some task when the app is closed. Something like Gmail who continue to notify all the time.

I found this : 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/background-mode/

But I want to create a specific service with specifics method who run in background. This plugin all the application run in background.

Someone can explain me how to do that ?

Comment: I'd seen this too. https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/service-worker/ But I don't think that would do what you want either, as yo uwnat it like some sort of background daemon notification service... My be worth looking to see if there's something in Cordova...

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md maybe this??? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dAcNtMQBNY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to keep to received notifications when app is closed. I try a solution : Use Push Notification, Firebase for Android and APNS for iOS. 
This solution works but with 2 problems :

- Have to use external services
- It can be a little bit hard to configure

I hope this can help. I know I don't explain how we can have a service to run in background ... But that is the solution for my problem.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. Could you please help me how to invoke a service in background?